# JQuery selectors for JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Is there a way to query JavaScript objects with JQuery selectors?

For example, consider an array:

```
var users = [{id: 0, username: 'Alice'}, {id: 1, username: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, username: 'Cindy'}];
```

, then the following works fine:

```
$(users).each(function (index, user) { ... });
```

I need to be able do something like this:

```
$(users).find('[username="Bob"]').each(function(index, user){ ... });
```

, but I could figure out a proper selector string value. Any ideas?

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to do it, in particular, [`findWhere()`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere).

```
bobs = _.findWhere(users, { username: "Bob" });
```

If you must use jQuery, you could use...

```
bobs = $.grep(users, function(user) { return user.username === "Bob"; });
```

Or if your platforms support `Array.prototype.filter()`, use it in the same way you use jQuery's `grep()`.

Also, when iterating over something with jQuery that isn't a jQuery collection, don't use `jQuery.prototype.each()`, but use `jQuery.each()`.

Comment: ... but use `Array.prototype.forEach()` ;-P

Comment: @zerkms Definitely, if your target platforms support it.

Comment: Thank you! `jQuery.prototype.each()` vs. `jQuery.each()` - could you, please, elaborate why?

Comment: The first is made for jQuery collections, the second for any array-like object.

Answer (score 3):

use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), a native javascript function

```
users.filter(function(user) { return user.username === "Bob"; }) ;
```